# erlang - passing a number as the Name argument to register/2

Tags: erlang

When using register/2, I get an error when I try to pass a number as the process name argument. Here I try to name the shell process '1', and get the following error:

```
43> register(1,self()).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  register/2
        called as register(1,<0.93.0>)
```

Contrast this to naming the shell 'shelly':

```
44> register(shelly,self()).
true
```

The documentation says the Name argument in register(Name,PID) has to be an atom. I thought the number 1 was indeed an atom.

My question is: how do pass successfully pass a number to register/2, such that passing the bound variable P=1, for example, succeeds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An atom is a symbol, nothing to do with integers. There is no direct conversion from integer to atom, but you can use an intermediate list for that:

```
1> Int_to_atom = fun(X) -> list_to_atom(integer_to_list(X)) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.106461118>
2> Int_to_atom(2).                                              
'2'
3> P = 1.
1
4> Int_to_atom(P).
'1'
5>
```

Comment: Or as specified in http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id66656: "An atom should be enclosed in single quotes (') if it does not begin with a lower-case letter or if it contains other characters than alphanumeric characters, underscore (_), or @.". Hence you can type '2' in the shell to create an atom out of an integer.

Comment: be careful doing this without a fixed list of numbers to do it from, you will leak atoms, maybe prefer list_to_existing_atom and define your atoms explicitly

Answer (score 2):

From the [Erlang documentation on datatypes](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html):

> An atom is a literal, a constant with name. An atom should be enclosed
>   in single quotes (') if it does not begin with a lower-case letter or
>   if it contains other characters than alphanumeric characters,
>   underscore (_), or @.

You can do

```
register('1',self()).
```

(Note the single-quotes, making this an atom and not a number. You can see that it's not a number but an atom by trying

```
'1' + 1
```

You were probably thinking of "*term*" when you expected them to be interchangeable. An Erlang *term* is an singular piece of data. Some examples of things that are terms:

- an atom
- a number
- a tuple (itself containing more terms)
- a list (itself containing more terms)
- a binary
- a function